# Filling in hourly buckets of activity time - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counting, python-datetime

I have a list of devices and their activity time (start time and end time). A device can have one or more activity logs. What I am trying to do is to create a distribution for each device of when the device was active.

My current dataframe looks something like this:

```
device_id start_time end_time
1 03:53 10:54
1 06:00 14:00
2 20:29 06:17
```

To create a distribution of activity time for each device, I thought I would create hourly buckets (corresponding to hours from 00 to 23) and fill in the buckets where the device was active. So for device 1, for example, the first row would be

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

and the second row

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

adding them up to create a distribution of activity for device 1 would give:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I had the following attempt to create the needed lists, however, it only works if end time is greater than start time (e.g. the first two rows in the data sample above) and won't work for start time greater than end time (e.g. row 3 in the data sample above).

```
for start, end in zip(df[df['start_time'].notnull() & df['end_time'].notnull()]['start_time'],df[df['start_time'].notnull() & df['end_time'].notnull()]['end_time']) :
    start_time = pd.to_datetime(start, format ='%H:%M')
    end_time = pd.to_datetime(end, format ='%H:%M')
    activity = [0]*24
    i = (start_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=((start_time.minute // 60 + (1 if start_time.minute>30 else 0) ) * 60) - start_time.minute)).hour
    rounded_end_time = (end_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=((end_time.minute // 60 + (1 if end_time.minute>30 else 0) ) * 60) - end_time.minute)).hour
    while i < rounded_end_time:
        activity[i] = 1
        i = i + 1
    print activity
```

Any suggestions for a fix? (or a smarter way to accomplish the task in the first place?)

Comment: How do you interpret a row where the start time is greater than the end time?  I.e. what does that actually represent in terms of real information?

Comment: @8one6 it means the device has been running overnight. The third row, for example, should fill the first 6 indices and the last 4 in the hourly buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I am posting the answer with comments just in case someone needs it:

```
# for each pair of start and end time that are not null
for start, end in zip(df[df['start_time'].notnull() & df['end_time'].notnull()]['start_time'],df[df['start_time'].notnull() & df['end_time'].notnull()]['end_time']) :

   start_time = pd.to_datetime(start, format ='%H:%M')
   end_time = pd.to_datetime(end, format ='%H:%M')
   #create a list of 24 indexes and initialize them to 0
   activity = [0]*24
   #round start and end time to the nearest hour
   i = (start_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=((start_time.minute // 60 + (1 if start_time.minute>30 else 0) ) * 60) - start_time.minute)).hour
   rounded_end_time = (end_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=((end_time.minute // 60 + (1 if end_time.minute>30 else 0) ) * 60) - end_time.minute)).hour
   #calculate the number of hours of activity (which is also the number of buckets to be filled)    
   duration = (pd.to_datetime(rounded_end_time , format ='%H') - pd.to_datetime(i, format ='%H')).seconds//3600
   #initialize a count to count the number of buckets we fill 
   count = 0
   while duration > count:
      activity[i] = 1
      count = count +1
      #set the index of the bucket to be filled to the next indes, unless it goes beyond the last bucket, in which case continue from the first bucket 
      i = (i+1 if i+1 < 24 else 0)
   print activity
```

Comment: When i tried your solution it is not marking 1 between 3-4 and since start time is 3:54 it should have marked 1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using only pandas like below:

```
x=pd.DataFrame([[1, '03:53', '10:54'],[1, '06:00', '14:00'],[2, '20:29', '06:17']])
x.columns=['device_id', 'start_time', 'end_time']
x['start_time']=pd.to_datetime(x['start_time'],format ='%H:%M')
x['end_time']=pd.to_datetime(x['end_time'],format ='%H:%M')
x['type'] = x['end_time']-x['start_time']>0
x['type'] = x['type'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x else 1)
x['min'] = x[['start_time','end_time']].min(axis=1)
x['max'] = x[['start_time','end_time']].max(axis=1)
for i in range(24):
    h = '0'+str(i)
    h = h[-2:]
    l = x['min']<=pd.to_datetime(h + ':59',format ='%H:%M')
    e = x['max']>=pd.to_datetime(h+':00',format ='%H:%M')
    l=l.apply(lambda x: 1 if x else -1)
    e=e.apply(lambda x: 1 if x else -1)
    x[i]=l+e+x['type']
    x[i]=x[i].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 and x < 3 else 0)
x = x.drop(['start_time','end_time'],axis=1).groupby('device_id').agg(np.max)
x.reset_index().drop('device_id',axis=1).sum()
```

Comment: My main problem is the case when start time is greater than end time. I do not have the full date, unfortunately, just the time in 24h format. This suggested solution does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Fate: I've edited my solution to solve problem you've raised. For larger datasets it shoould be much faster than iterating over lists.

Answer (score 0):

Taking rows of start/end times and binning them into time buckets (total duration of minutes in this case)

Note: not all edge cases have been covered but you can expand on the code if you find it useful

```
#your imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Hour, Minute
#optional
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

# construct a sample raw data dataframe
start_times = ['2000-01-01 09:00', '2000-01-01 10:00']
end_times = ['2000-01-01 17:00', '2000-01-01 18:00']
index = ['Timeframe ' + str(i) for i in range(len(start_times))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Time': pd.to_datetime(start_times),
              'End Time' : pd.to_datetime(end_times)}, index=index)
```

The dataframe **df** will look similar to below

```
               End Time               Start Time
```

**Timeframe 0**   2000-01-01 17:00:00   2000-01-01 09:00:00
**Timeframe 1**   2000-01-01 18:00:00   2000-01-01 10:00:00

```
#Construct your dataframe for time buckets
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01 09:00', periods=9, freq='H')
ts = pd.DataFrame(0, index=rng, columns=['minutes'], dtype='float')
```

The dataframe **ts** will look similar to below

```
                     minutes
```

**2000-01-01 09:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 10:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 11:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 12:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 13:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 14:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 15:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 16:00:00**   0.0
**2000-01-01 17:00:00**   0.0

```
for index, row in ts.iterrows():
    #set_trace()
    start_boundary = index
    end_boundary = index + Hour()
    time_count = pd.Timedelta('0 m')
        for _, raw_data in df.iterrows():
            #set_trace()
            start_time = raw_data['Start Time']
            end_time = raw_data['End Time']
            if end_time > start_boundary:
                if start_time < end_boundary:
                    if start_time <= start_boundary:
                        if end_time >= end_boundary:
                            time_count = time_count + (end_boundary - start_boundary)
                        else:
                            time_count = time + (end_time - start_boundary)
                    else:
                        if end_time >= end_boundary:
                            time_count = time_count + (end_boundary - start_time)
                        else:
                            time_count = time_count + (end_time - start_time)
    #set_trace()
    ts.at[index, 'minutes'] = time_count.seconds / 60
```

Run the code above and your **ts** dataframe (see below) should have total duration in minutes binned based on the raw data in the **df** dataframe

```
                     minutes
```

**2000-01-01 09:00:00**   60.0
**2000-01-01 10:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 11:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 12:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 13:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 14:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 15:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 16:00:00**   120.0
**2000-01-01 17:00:00**   60.0